# css components and responsive coupling - best practices?

Tags: css, sass, responsive

Say I create a component like a table that I wish to reuse across different pages. The content and number of columns in the table will vary from page to page, but the look and feel should be the same.

```
.my-table {
    background-color: ... etc
    color: ... etc
}
```

When making this component responsive - should each page have it's own set of media queries that alters the look of this component, or should the component itself define the queries?

Ie. I may want to hide columns 3 and 5 of this table when viewing on mobile, but on another page there may only be 3 columns and I don't want column 3 to be hidden on that page. What is the better practice to use in this case? Should the responsive logic be decoupled from the component styles?

Another example - most css guides i've read recommend doing something like this:

```
.layout-columns-2 {
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
}

.layout-columns-4 {
     float: left;
     width: 25%;
}
```

Which you can reuse on layouts whenever you need columns to float side by side. But again you run into similar issues the moment you try applying responsive rules.

Say for example on one page, you want to break the float of a particular div when the width is 600px so that the columns are stacked vertically. But on another section of the page, you want the float to break at 800px. What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a [Sass partial](http://sass-lang.com/guide) with some table mixins, which can be applied as needed. This will let you decouple your table "modules" from your actual tables. Decoupling is usually a good thing, as it lets you add and change styles with greater ease and consistency.

Since you want your breakpoints to vary from table to table, I would leave the table styles as "mobile-first" by default, and customize them one-by-one as appropriate.

**_tables.scss:**

```
table {
  // Global, mobile-first styles go here
}

@mixin columns-2() {
  td {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@mixin columns-4() {
  td {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}

// Function to return a max breakpoint (1px less)
@function max-break($size) {
  @return $size - .0625em;
}
```

Using your partial, you can apply your mixins as appropriate for any specific table ...

**special-page.scss:**

```
@import 'tables';

.my-table {
  // Hide columns 2/4 below 800px
  @media (max-width: max-break(50em)) {
    td:nth-child(2),
    td:nth-child(4) {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  // Use 2 columns at 600px
  @media (min-width: 37.5em) {
    @include columns-2();
  }

  // Use 4 columns at 600px    
  @media (min-width: 50em) {
    @include columns-4();
  }
}
```